# Overlapping tables in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am creating tables to share links of interest with my students. I do this using RMarkdown in RStudio and GitHub. The tables are in an HTML format and I determine the style of the tables using CSS. There are four tables that I would like to place in four quadrants. However, the first two are side by side in the correct way and the last two (from quadrants 3 and 4) overlap, see [this link](https://fsbmat-ufv.github.io/#/posts/Links). How to fix this error?

The main file can be found at this [link](https://github.com/fsbmat-ufv/fsbmat-ufv.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2019-01-01-Links.markdown).

```css
table.table-style-two {
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #333333;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #3A3A3A;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.table-style-two th {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #517994;
  background-color: #B2CFD8;
}

table.table-style-two tr:hover td {
  background-color: #DFEBF1;
}

table.table-style-two td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #517994;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.floatLeft {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.floatRight {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!--Tabelas de Cursos e Webinarios-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="floatLeft">
    <!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
    <!-- Tabela 1 (Cursos) -->
    <table class="table-style-two">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="4">
            <center> Cursos </center>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <center> Quantidade </center>
          </th>
          <th>
            <center> Descrição </center>
          </th>
          <th>
            <center> Links </center>
          </th>
          <th>
            <center> Observações </center>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center> 1 </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> Cursos Diversos </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> <a href="   http://veduca.org/  " target="_blank">  Veduca  </a> </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center> 2 </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> Ciência de Dados </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> <a href="   https://www.datascienceacademy.com.br/  " target="_blank">  Data Science Academy    </a> </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center> 3 </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> Programação </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> <a href="   https://medium.com/lambda-school-blog   " target="_blank">  Lambda  </a> </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

  <div class="floatRight">
    <tr>
      <!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
      <!-- Tabela 2 (Webinários) -->
      <!--Substituir A partir daqui-->
      <table class="table-style-two">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="4">
              <center> Webinários </center>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <center> Quantidade </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> Descrição </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> Links </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> Observações </center>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center> 1 </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <a href="   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-DGDNepTno&feature=youtu.be    " target="_blank"> </a>
              </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center> 2 </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <a href="   https://youtu.be/_-DGDNepTno    " target="_blank"> </a>
              </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center> 3 </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <a href="   https://youtu.be/lYqEw_VZqV4    " target="_blank"> </a>
              </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!--Substituir ate a linha anterior-->
      <br>
      <br>
      <!--Tabelas de Cursos e Webinarios-->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="floatLeft">
          <!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
          <!-- Tabela 1 (Cursos) -->
          <!--Substituir A partir daqui-->
          <table class="table-style-two">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="4">
                  <center> Cursos </center>
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <center> Quantidade </center>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <center> Descrição </center>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <center> Links </center>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <center> Observações </center>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <center> 1 </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> Cursos Diversos </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> <a href="   http://veduca.org/  " target="_blank">  Veduca  </a> </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <center> 2 </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> Ciência de Dados </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> <a href="   https://www.datascienceacademy.com.br/  " target="_blank">  Data Science Academy    </a> </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <center> 3 </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> Programação </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> <a href="   https://medium.com/lambda-school-blog   " target="_blank">  Lambda  </a> </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <center> 4 </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> Programação </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> <a href="   https://www.codeavengers.com/   " target="_blank">  Code Avenger    </a> </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!--Substituir ate a linha anterior-->
        </div>
        <div class="floatRight">
          <tr>
            <!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
            <!-- Tabela 2 (Webinários) -->
            <!--Substituir A partir daqui-->
            <table class="table-style-two">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="4">
                    <center> Webinários </center>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    <center> Quantidade </center>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <center> Descrição </center>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <center> Links </center>
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <center> Observações </center>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <center> 1 </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center>
                      <a href="   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-DGDNepTno&feature=youtu.be    " target="_blank"> </a>
                    </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center> </center>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <center> 2 </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center>
                      <a href="   https://youtu.be/_-DGDNepTno    " target="_blank"> </a>
                    </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center> </center>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <center> 3 </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center>
                      <a href="   https://youtu.be/lYqEw_VZqV4    " target="_blank"> </a>
                    </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center> </center>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <center> 4 </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center>
                      <a href="   https://youtu.be/8PYG89fD8jQ    " target="_blank"> </a>
                    </center>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <center> </center>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `div`s are nested incorrectly - table 3 is inside the floated div for table 2.

Also FYI your HTML is invalid - you are not closing div tags

Here is the correctly nested version (although it might be worth looking into grids instead of using floats):

**UPDATE**: Added comments to make it easier to find the lines to be changed

```css
table.table-style-two {
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #333333;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #3A3A3A;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
}

table.table-style-two th {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #517994;
  background-color: #B2CFD8;
}

table.table-style-two tr:hover td {
  background-color: #DFEBF1;
}

table.table-style-two td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #517994;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.floatLeft {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.floatRight {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!--Tabelas de Cursos e Webinarios-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="floatLeft">
    <!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
    <!-- Tabela 1 (Cursos) -->
    <table class="table-style-two">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="4">
            <center> Cursos </center>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <center> Quantidade </center>
          </th>
          <th>
            <center> Descrição </center>
          </th>
          <th>
            <center> Links </center>
          </th>
          <th>
            <center> Observações </center>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center> 1 </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> Cursos Diversos </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> <a href="   http://veduca.org/  " target="_blank">  Veduca  </a> </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center> 2 </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> Ciência de Dados </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> <a href="   https://www.datascienceacademy.com.br/  " target="_blank">  Data Science Academy    </a> </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center> 3 </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> Programação </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> <a href="   https://medium.com/lambda-school-blog   " target="_blank">  Lambda  </a> </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="floatRight">
    <tr>
      <!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
      <!-- Tabela 2 (Webinários) -->
      <!--Substituir A partir daqui-->
      <table class="table-style-two">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="4">
              <center> Webinários </center>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <center> Quantidade </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> Descrição </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> Links </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> Observações </center>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center> 1 </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <a href="   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-DGDNepTno&feature=youtu.be    " target="_blank"> </a>
              </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center> 2 </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <a href="   https://youtu.be/_-DGDNepTno    " target="_blank"> </a>
              </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center> 3 </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <a href="   https://youtu.be/lYqEw_VZqV4    " target="_blank"> </a>
              </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!--Substituir ate a linha anterior-->
  </div>                                 /* 1. CLOSE FIRST floatRight HERE */
</div>                                   /* 2. CLOSE FIRST container HERE */
<br>
<br>


/* 3. NOW THIS ISN'T INSIDE TABLE 2'S  floatRight DIV ANYMORE SO IT WILL FLOAT OVER TO THE LEFT, UNDER TABLE 1 */
<div class="container">
  <!--Tabelas de Cursos e Webinarios-->
  <div class="floatLeft">
    <!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
    <!-- Tabela 1 (Cursos) -->
    <!--Substituir A partir daqui-->
    <table class="table-style-two">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="4">
            <center> Cursos </center>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <center> Quantidade </center>
          </th>
          <th>
            <center> Descrição </center>
          </th>
          <th>
            <center> Links </center>
          </th>
          <th>
            <center> Observações </center>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center> 1 </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> Cursos Diversos </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> <a href="   http://veduca.org/  " target="_blank">  Veduca  </a> </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center> 2 </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> Ciência de Dados </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> <a href="   https://www.datascienceacademy.com.br/  " target="_blank">  Data Science Academy    </a> </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center> 3 </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> Programação </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> <a href="   https://medium.com/lambda-school-blog   " target="_blank">  Lambda  </a> </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <center> 4 </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> Programação </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> <a href="   https://www.codeavengers.com/   " target="_blank">  Code Avenger    </a> </center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center> </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--Substituir ate a linha anterior-->
  </div>
  <div class="floatRight">
    <tr>
      <!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
      <!-- Tabela 2 (Webinários) -->
      <!--Substituir A partir daqui-->
      <table class="table-style-two">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="4">
              <center> Webinários </center>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <center> Quantidade </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> Descrição </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> Links </center>
            </th>
            <th>
              <center> Observações </center>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center> 1 </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <a href="   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-DGDNepTno&feature=youtu.be    " target="_blank"> </a>
              </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center> 2 </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <a href="   https://youtu.be/_-DGDNepTno    " target="_blank"> </a>
              </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center> 3 </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <a href="   https://youtu.be/lYqEw_VZqV4    " target="_blank"> </a>
              </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <center> 4 </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <a href="   https://youtu.be/8PYG89fD8jQ    " target="_blank"> </a>
              </center>
            </td>
            <td>
              <center> </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>

/* 4. MAKE SURE TO REMOVE THE CLOSING </div> TAGS HERE THAT WERE FOR floatRight AND THE FIRST container div */
```

Comment: In fact, </div> was not closing properly, this is because the page (https://fsbmat-ufv.github.io/#/posts/Links) is not rendering correctly!

Comment: @fsbmat I'm not sure what you mean? Does this answer not fix the problem? It fixes the code you added your the question, which is what we work with - we don#'t work with code in external links because it can change over time, making the question irrelevant, so the relevant code should be in the question itself.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem, my tables are still overlapping!

Comment: It works with the code you provided, as you can see when you run the snippet in my answer - did you try running the snippet? The problem is with the table in the wrong floated div. If it is not working in any external code then the problem is somewhere else - we can only fix the code you show us! As I said, code in external links doesn't count - you need to edit the code in the question with whatever else is causing the problem. I resume it is because you have more unclosed or mis-matched `div`s, but we're not here to debug your entire code :)

Comment: The lack of the div was in fact a mistake in my code, but the error doesn't happen because of that!

Comment: @fsbmat I know. As I said, the problem is because table 3 is inside the table 2's floated div. That's what I fixed in my code, as you can see when you run the snippet!

Comment: I understand you and I will accept your answer, however, I continue with the overlapping tables on the website I shared!

Comment: @fsbmat But you don't need to continue with overlapping divs! This puts table 3 over to the left under table 1 instead of under table 2... is this not what you were trying to do, or was it something else you wanted to do?

Comment: Yes, I want table 1 and 3 on the left and table 2 and 4 on the right.

Comment: @fsbmat You just need to move the 2nd `<div class="container">` and the `<div class="floatLeft">` for table 3 out of the `<div class="floatRight">` for table 2. (Or to put it another way, close the first `<div class="container">` and `<div class="floatLeft">` blocks *before* the `<br.<br>`tags so that the second container isn't inside the `<div class="floatRight">` for table 2)

Comment: This is what you did in your code, unfortunately it didn't work on my page. There may be something wrong on the page! Thank you!

Comment: @fsbmat I've looked at your page again and I can now see the `</div>` tags appearing in the text on your page, rather than as HTML - *this* is what is causing the problem so that's what you need to fix. If you are using a CMS with a text editor, the closing tags might have been added as text rather than HTML. I also see that you are using some sort of code minimiser on the website - so maybe this is not recognising the closing tags. But that is the real root of the problem. However we can't help with fixing that because its inside your CMS admin so we can't see what's happening :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is a [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

To get the four tables in four quadrants you may use the simplest grid:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      tabela 1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      tabela 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      tabela 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      tabela 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code and managed to solve the problem, here is my solution:

```css
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">                                                                                                
table.table-style-two {
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #333333;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #3A3A3A;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
}

table.table-style-two th {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #517994;
  background-color: #B2CFD8;
}

table.table-style-two tr:hover td {
  background-color: #DFEBF1;
}

table.table-style-two td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #517994;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.floatLeft {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.floatRight {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="Div1" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: left;">
    <table class="table-style-two">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="4">
                <center> Cursos </center>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <center> Quantidade </center>
              </th>
              <th>
                <center> Descrição </center>
              </th>
              <th>
                <center> Links </center>
              </th>
              <th>
                <center> Observações </center>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center> 1 </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> Cursos Diversos </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> <a href="   http://veduca.org/  " target="_blank">  Veduca  </a> </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center> 2 </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> Ciência de Dados </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> <a href="   https://www.datascienceacademy.com.br/  " target="_blank">  Data Science Academy    </a> </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center> 3 </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> Programação </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> <a href="   https://medium.com/lambda-school-blog   " target="_blank">  Lambda  </a> </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="Div2" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: left;">
    <table class="table-style-two">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="4">
                  <center> Webinários </center>
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <center> Quantidade </center>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <center> Descrição </center>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <center> Links </center>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <center> Observações </center>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <center> 1 </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <a href="   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-DGDNepTno&feature=youtu.be    " target="_blank"> </a>
                  </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <center> 2 </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <a href="   https://youtu.be/_-DGDNepTno    " target="_blank"> </a>
                  </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <center> 3 </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <a href="   https://youtu.be/lYqEw_VZqV4    " target="_blank"> </a>
                  </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
    
    
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    
    
    <div id="Div3" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: right;">
    <table class="table-style-two">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="4">
                  <center> Webinários </center>
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <center> Quantidade </center>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <center> Descrição </center>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <center> Links </center>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <center> Observações </center>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <center> 1 </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <a href="   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-DGDNepTno&feature=youtu.be    " target="_blank"> </a>
                  </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <center> 2 </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <a href="   https://youtu.be/_-DGDNepTno    " target="_blank"> </a>
                  </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <center> 3 </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> PPG Estatística - UFRGS </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center>
                    <a href="   https://youtu.be/lYqEw_VZqV4    " target="_blank"> </a>
                  </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <center> </center>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="Div4" style="width: 50%;height: 30px;float: right;">
    <table class="table-style-two">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="4">
                <center> Cursos </center>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <center> Quantidade </center>
              </th>
              <th>
                <center> Descrição </center>
              </th>
              <th>
                <center> Links </center>
              </th>
              <th>
                <center> Observações </center>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center> 1 </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> Cursos Diversos </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> <a href="   http://veduca.org/  " target="_blank">  Veduca  </a> </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center> 2 </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> Ciência de Dados </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> <a href="   https://www.datascienceacademy.com.br/  " target="_blank">  Data Science Academy    </a> </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center> 3 </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> Programação </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> <a href="   https://medium.com/lambda-school-blog   " target="_blank">  Lambda  </a> </center>
              </td>
              <td>
                <center> </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```